# Binary Search keeps returning -1?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, search, binary

This method is supposed to pass an array of objects:

```
Movie[] movieList = new Movie[6];
    movieList[0] = new Drama("Titanic","James Cameron", 1997, 200.0, 80.0, 7.50);
    movieList[1] = new Drama("Fight Club", "David Fincher", 1999, 63.0, 30.0, 6.50);
    movieList[2] = new Animated("Spirited Away", "Hayao Miyazaki", 2001, 19.1, 2.0, 30.0);
    movieList[3] = new Animated("Toy Story", "John Lassater", 1995, 30.0, 3.5, 200.0);
    movieList[4] = new Documentary("Super Size Me","Morgan Spurlock", 2004, 0.006, 35, .005);
    movieList[5] = new Documentary("Jiro Dreams", "David Gelb", 2011, 0.003, 26, .002);
```

and is supposed to organize and search by the title of the movie.
However, each time i try and pass the objects into the method using a switch statement:

```
case 3:
    System.out.println("Please input the movie you are searching for:");
    key = input.nextLine();
    key = input.nextLine();
    if(searchMovies(movieList, key)== -1)
    {
        System.out.println("There is no match found for movie with title " + key);
    } 
    else 
    {
        index = (searchMovies(movieList, key));
        System.out.println(movieList[index].toString());
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
    break;
```

All that is returned is either a negative 1 which tells me it could not find the key,
or an error saying that the Array Index is out of bounds.
Here is the searchMovies method containing the Bubble sort and Binary Search method

```
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------
//searchMovies first sorts the array of objects by title through Bubble
//Sort and then searches the array using Binary Search for the users
//key.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
public static int searchMovies(Movie[] movieList, String key)
{
    //Bubble Sort the titles
    boolean needNextPass = true;
    Movie temp;
    for(int pass=1; pass<movieList.length && needNextPass; pass++)
    {
        needNextPass = false;  // Array may be sorted and next pass not needed
        for(int x=0; x<movieList.length-pass; x++)
            if(((Profitable) movieList[x]).calcProfit() < ((Profitable) movieList[x+1]).calcProfit())  /** compare rental fee */
            {
                temp = movieList[x];
                movieList[x] = movieList[x+1];
                movieList[x+1] = temp;

                needNextPass = true; // Next pass still needed
            }
     }//end for
    //Binary search for key
    int first = 0;
    int last = movieList.length;

    while (first <= last) {
        int mid =(first + last) / 2; // Compute mid point.
        if (key.compareTo(movieList[mid].getTitle()) < 0) {
            last = mid; // repeat search in bottom half.
        } else if (key.compareTo(movieList[mid].getTitle()) > 0) {
            first = mid + 1; // Repeat search in top half.
        } else {
            return mid; // Found it. return position
        }//end if
    }//end loop
    return -1; // Failed to find key
}//end searchMovies'
```

Comment: Why did you call `key=input.nextLine();` twice?

Comment: First thing to do: separate out the bubble sort from the binary search. Then you can easily test each separately.

Comment: Why are you scanning input twice `Key=input.nextLine()` ?

Answer (score 0):

You bubble sort your movies based on `calcProfit()` but then you try to search based on `getTitle()`.

A binary search is only guaranteed to work if the list you are searching is considered sorted from the perspective of the comparision function that you are using to search the list. In your case the list would have to be sorted based on `getTitle()` for you to be able to use binary search.

Additionally, the reason you may be getting the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsError` is because you set the maximum index of binary search to be `moviesList.length`. You should instead set it to `moviesList.length-1`

Answer (score 0):

Your array of movies need to be sorted according to your `title`, because you are using `title` to decide which of the halves to choose, to search for the next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

As others suggested, when using binary search you need to have the array sorted by the key you are using for comparison (this would be `title` in your case).

In your binary search algorithm you should modify the way you assign your indexes as following:

```
int first = 0;
int last = movieList.length - 1; // last index is (length-1) in an array, not length. Trying to access length will produce an `AraryIndexOutOfBounds`

while (first <= last) {
    int mid = (first + last) / 2; 
    if (key.compareTo(movieList[mid].getTitle()) < 0) {
        last = mid - 1;  // Note the -1 here
    } else if (key.compareTo(movieList[mid].getTitle()) > 0) {
        first = mid + 1; 
    } else {
        return mid; 
    }
}
```

Personally I would use the above approach only if I was at a learning stage with algorithms and was trying to figure out how they work. In a real life scenario I would use something like below, because there is no need to re-invent the wheel:

```
Movie[] movies = ....;

// How our movies are compared to each other? This comparator compares using the titles
Comparator<Movie> titleComparator = new Comparator<Movie>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Movie o1, Movie o2) {
        return o1.title.compareTo(o2.title);
    }
};

// sort movies by title
Arrays.sort(movies, titleComparator);

String titleToFind = ...
Movie movieToFind = new UnknownMovie(titleToFind);

// perform a binary search to find that movie. If found returns the index
// if not found, returns a negative number that you can use to figure out where this movie should be inserted (see the documentation)
int index = Arrays.binarySearch(movies, movieToFind, titleComparator);
```

Hope that helps